# Not able to install codeception on MacBook using composer

Tags: macos, composer-php, codeception

I have a MacBook with Catalina 10.15.6
I have PHP and Composer installed.
I use the command composer require "codeception/codeception" --dev

And it just sits and waits.
what are we waiting for?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Like, using the `verbose` flag to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You executed some other composer application that you had installed in your system.

To use composer.phar file you have to execute it with PHP `php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception" --dev` or make it executable and run `./composer.phar require "codeception/codeception" --dev`